# Populate C# DataTable Asynchronously

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, datatable, async-await

I'm adding **async** implementations to all my SQL base classes used in my WebAPI projects. I'm fairly new to the TAP paradigm so I'm still learning.

I know, thanks to other posts, that spawning a thread via Task.Run() does not have any performance benefits in an ASP.NET context. So I'm being extra careful with my implementations.

I've changed my **QueryExecutor** method to the async implementation below. But cannot figure out what the best way to load the **DataTable** is. I'm guessing I would ideally want to use `reader.ReadAsync()` to populate the DataTable but it seems there isn't anything available in the .NET 4.5 framework for that.

So I wanted to ask would it be worth writing my own extension method such as `DataTable.LoadAsync(DbDataReader reader)`? I kind of don't want to if it can be helped since it won't be nearly as fool-proof as managed .Net code.

Let me know what you guys think.

```
private async Task<DataTable> ExecuteQueryInternalAsync(string commandText, CommandType commandType, SqlConnection sqlConnection, SqlTransaction transaction, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, sqlConnection) { CommandType = commandType, CommandTimeout = this.config.MainConnectionTimeoutInSeconds })
    {
        if (transaction != null)
            cmd.Transaction = transaction;

        if (parameters != null)
        {
            foreach (var parameter in parameters)
            {
                if (parameter != null)
                {
                    if (parameter.Value == null)
                        parameter.Value = DBNull.Value;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                }
            }
        }

        if (sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();

        using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
        {
            //Want to use: reader.ReadAsync()
            var tb = new DataTable();
            tb.Load(reader);
            return tb;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Just a sidenode: Your sample code is managed .Net code

Comment: Generally, asynchronous code uses Entity Framework queries rather than `DataTable`s.

Comment: I do use EF 6. But there are times when you need to just execute an SP and get the result as a DataTable.

Answer (score 4):

If you want an extension method, you can write directly on the command

```
public static class extensions
    {
         public async static Task<DataTable> ExecuteAndCreateDataTableAsync(this SqlCommand cmd)
         {
             using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
             {
                 var dataTable = reader.CreateTableSchema();
                 while (await reader.ReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
                 {
                     var dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
                     for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
                     {
                         dataRow[i] = reader[i];
                     }
                     dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
                 }
                 return dataTable;

             }
         }
         public static void LoadParams(this SqlCommand cmd, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
         {
             if (parameters != null)
             {
                 foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                 {
                     if (parameter != null)
                     {
                         if (parameter.Value == null)
                             parameter.Value = DBNull.Value;

                         cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                     }
                 }
             }
         }


         private static DataTable CreateTableSchema(this SqlDataReader reader)
         {
             DataTable schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
             DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
             if (schema != null)
             {
                 foreach (DataRow drow in schema.Rows)
                 {
                     string columnName = System.Convert.ToString(drow["ColumnName"]);
                     DataColumn column = new DataColumn(columnName, (Type)(drow["DataType"]));
                     dataTable.Columns.Add(column);
                 }
             }
             return dataTable;
         }
    }
```

and your medhod:

```
private async Task<DataTable> ExecuteQueryInternalAsync(string commandText, CommandType commandType, SqlConnection sqlConnection, SqlTransaction transaction, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, sqlConnection) { CommandType = commandType, CommandTimeout = this.config.MainConnectionTimeoutInSeconds })
            {
                if (transaction != null)
                    cmd.Transaction = transaction;

                cmd.LoadParams(parameters);

                if (sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();

                var datatable =  await cmd.ExecuteAndCreateDataTableAsync();
                return datatable;
            }
        }
```

Comment: So part of my question is, is it worth doing this? Is it worth using ReadAsync() instead of just populating the DataTable synchronously.

Comment: This is just implementation. I think it is unnecessary after ExecuteReaderAsync

Comment: It's been 6 years and I'm still curious if this would be better or worse for performance. Would the overhead of all the awaits outweigh the benefits of reading the data asynchronously?