# How to execute DataAdapter.Fill() simultaneously

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, stored-procedures, dataadapter

I have been working on an ASP.Net application for a long time and there are above 10 clients using the application. But now I found a problem in the application, that is, I have a stored procedure call which takes about 30 seconds to execute. It is not a problem, because the SQL code highly complicated and looping many times. The problem is :
 Whenever that stored procedure call is executing, I am not able to using any other functions or stored procedure call. 
When I tried debugging, the problem is that 'DataAdapter.Fill()' function is waiting for the first stored procedure call to finish.

My code that executes stored procedure call and returning data is :

```
public static DataSet ExecuteQuery_SP(string ProcedureName, object[,] ParamArray)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter DataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();       
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            if (CON.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                OpenConnection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
            cmd.CommandText = ProcedureName;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Connection = CON;
            cmd.Transaction = SqlTrans;
            string ParamName;
            object ParamValue;
            for (int i = 0; i < ParamArray.Length / 2; i++)
            {
                ParamName = ParamArray[i, 0].ToString();
                ParamValue = ParamArray[i, 1];
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(ParamName, ParamValue);
            }
            DataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataAdapter.Fill(DS);
            cmd.CommandText = "";
        }
           catch (Exception ea)
        {
        }
        return DS;
    }
```

All stored procedure calls are working through this function. Hence when my first stored procedure call 'A' is running, stored procedure call 'B' will not execute until 'A' is finished.

This reduces overall performance of the application and causes problem in data retrieval. 
I surfed google and found that 'Threading' can be helpful but I am not able to execute threading properly. I am not so familiar with these kind of things. It will helpful if you can rectify the problem. 
My first stored procedure call is:

```
 ds = DB.ExecuteQuery_SP("SelectOutstandingReportDetailed", parArray);
```

Where ds is the DataSet object.
Second stored procedure call is :

```
ds = DB.ExecuteQuery_SP("[SelectAccLedgersDetailsByID]", ParamArray);
```

My current DB connection open function is :

```
 public static bool OpenConnection() 
        {
            try
            {

                    Server = (String)HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("Resource", "Server");
                    DBName = (String)HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("Resource", "DBName");
                    UserName = (String)HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("Resource", "UserName");
                    PassWord = (String)HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("Resource", "PassWord");

                    string ConnectionString;
                    ConnectionString = "server=" + Server + "; database=" + DBName + "; uid=" + UserName + "; pwd=" + PassWord + "; Pooling='true';Max Pool Size=100;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Asynchronous Processing=true";

                    CON.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
                    if (CON.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        CON.Close();
                        CON.Open();
                    }

            }
            catch (Exception ea)
            {
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Where 'CON' is a public SqlConnection variable

```
static SqlConnection CON = new SqlConnection();
```

I found the problem, that is, all stored procedure calls are performed through this 'CON' object. If there is seperate SqlConnection object for each stored procedure call, then no problem is there. 
So is it possible to make separate SqlConnection for every ExecuteQuery_SP calls.
If any doubt in question, kindly comment.
Thank you

Comment: "All stored procedure calls are working through this function." Then don't use the same method to execute different stored procedures?

Comment: ExecuteQuery_SP function is a common function for that open database connection. I cannot give separate functions for each stored procedure calls, because there will be about hundred stored procedure calls @IrishChieftain

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/synclock-statement  -- Have you tried this?  Sorry, wrong language at first.  Let me see if C# has something similar.

Comment: That's what's called a data layer. You have different data access methods, each of which could potentially call a stored procedure. Give it a try.

Comment: Here is the C# reference for locking it down to one thread at a time: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

Comment: JohnPete22, that's just going to make it worse.

Comment: @JohnPete22 I want to run both the stored procedures at the same time. Your reference doesn't do the job.

Comment: I am not getting about data layer. I am just a beginner in this. If you can explain, it will be helpful @IrishChieftain

Comment: What transaction are you using? Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: What you mean? @AlexanderPetrov

Comment: You are using `cmd.Transaction = SqlTrans;` This transaction is passed from the outside. What are the settings for this transaction? What other queries are executed in the same transaction? Are there any deadlocks?

Comment: Are you using a single `SqlConnection` for all data access? You shouldn't do that. Create a new `SqlConnection` for each request. ADO.NET manages a [connection pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling) internally.

Comment: From the function ExecuteQuery_SP you can see that whenever the current connection is closed, a new connection is opened. I tried opening connection for every stored procedure call, but still the same result @TheodorZoulias

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server will allow [thousands of connections](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5766/managing-maximum-number-of-concurrent-connections-in-sql-server/) simultaneously, by default. This is NOT the source of your problem. You have forced every call to a stored procedure to be funneled through a single method. Factor out your calls to the stored procedures - in other words, lose the ExecuteQuery_SP method which is a bottleneck. Then test again.

Here's is an introduction to [data layers](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7be47b/how-to-implement-3-tier-architecture-concepts-in-Asp-Net/).

Comment: I didn't get you properly. Do you mean write separate ExecuteQuery_SP like functions for every stored procedure call?

Comment: Yes. You are creating a bottleneck unnecessarily.

Comment: Sorry, it's not possible in my case. Because there are large amount of stored procedure calls.

Comment: I tried adding seperate function for 'SelectOutstandingReportDetailed', but the problem persists.

Comment: Did you just call 'SelectOutstandingReportDetailed' and not any others sprocs? Is there a problem with queries with many joins? Maybe missing a DB index? You need to narrow this down.

Comment: No. There are many sprocs I usually call. Just for example I used this 'SelectOutstandingReportDetailed' and it takes some time to finish executeion. What you mean by DB index?

Comment: You can't solve a problem until you know what the problem is. You need to identify exactly where the performance hit is taking place. Is it a specific query? Nobody can answer this for you until the problem is identified. Either way, you need to lose the ExecuteQuery_SP method.

Comment: Which stored procedure is taking 30 seconds to execute? Start there and use SQL Profiler to see if there's a problem with the query itself. This may not be about concurrency at all.

Comment: The problem is there with DataAdapter.Fill(DS) method. When 'SelectOutstandingReportDetailed' runs DataAadapter.Fill(DS) then other stored procedure calls will just wait at DataAdapter.Fill(DS) until previous execution is finished.

Comment: I told you to get rid of that method. I can only explain it so many ways. Run your queries independently in SSMS and see what's happening. Nobody here knows your code or how many queries are being chained one after the other.

Comment: There is no problem with the query, there are some while loops in it, hence it takes time to execute. That is not the problem, whenever one query is processing another storedprocedurecall cannot be processed.

Comment: I already told you why this is happening. Don't be calling all your stored procedures from the same method. Have you checked all the other queries?

Comment: The problem is not related to the query. Some queries take time it's not a problem. But I want to execute multiple stored procedures at the same time. I already tried making separate function for my first stored procedure call, but still it remains same. That is the sqladapter.fill is not executing when previous sqladapter.fill is not completed execution.

Comment: Yes, but did you isolate it? We cannot see your entire code. Either way, you should not be using one method to call all stored procedures. Having multiple stored procedures executing at the same time should not be a problem. Like I said, this doesn't sound like a concurrency issue per say...

Comment: I found the problem and updated the question. Please check it.

Comment: Best of luck. I still don't understand the question.

Comment: Problem is, all my stored procedure call are being done with sqlconnection CON. So when one stored procedure call is currently working then we cannot use the same CON for another stored procedure call. I tried by creating SqlConnection and it's working

Answer (score 0):

Heres the simplest version I can create for you.
Important: to understand you **should** read  about async-await.

You can start at the [Microsoft C# Async-Await Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

```
// TODO set up your connection string
    private string connectionString = "<your connection string>";

    // Gets data assyncronously
    public static async Task<DataTable> GetDataAsync(string procedureName, object[,] ParamArray)
    {
        try
        {
            var asyncConnectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString)
            {
                AsynchronousProcessing = true
            }.ToString();

            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(asyncConnectionString))
            {
                using (var SqlCommand = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    SqlCommand.Connection = conn;
                    SqlCommand.CommandText = procedureName;
                    SqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    string ParamName;
                    object ParamValue;
                    for (int i = 0; i < ParamArray.Length / 2; i++)
                    {
                        ParamName = ParamArray[i, 0].ToString();
                        ParamValue = ParamArray[i, 1];
                        SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(ParamName, ParamValue);
                    }

                    conn.Open();
                    var data = new DataTable();
                    data.BeginLoadData();
                    using (var reader = await SqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync().ConfigureAwait(true))
                    {
                        if (reader.HasRows)
                            data.Load(reader);
                    }
                    data.EndLoadData();
                    return data;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            // Log error or something else
            throw;
        }
    }

    public static async Task<DataTable> GetData(object General, object Type, string FromDate, string ToDate)
    {
        object[,] parArray = new object[,]{
        {"@BranchID",General.BranchID},
        {"@FinancialYearID",General.FinancialYearID},
        {"@Type",Type},
        {"@FromDate",DateTime.ParseExact(FromDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)},
        {"@ToDate",DateTime.ParseExact(ToDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}
        };

        return await DataBaseHelper.GetDataAsync("SelectOutstandingReportDetailed", parArray);
    }

    // Calls database assyncronously
    private async Task ConsumeData()
    {
        DataTable dt = null;

        try
        {
            // TODO configure your parameters here
            object general = null;
            object type = null;
            string fromDate = "";
            string toDate = "";

            dt = await GetData(general, type, fromDate, toDate);
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            // do something if an error occurs
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error occurred: " + Ex.ToString());
            return;
        }

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dr.ToString());
        }
    }

    // Fired when some button is clicked. Get and use the data assyncronously, i.e. without blocking the UI.
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await ConsumeData();
    }
```

Comment: I will try with this, but it is seen very complicated for me because I am not at all familiar with this. I will try my best with this. If you can please help me with my code

Comment: whats the parameters of "SelectOutstandingReportDetailed" ? if you give-me I can show you my approach.

Comment: And, I'm curious. How do you create the ParamArray variable? Is It like [ ["@varname",value], ["@varname2",value] ] ? I can't understand.

Comment: object[,] parArray = new object[,]{
                {"@BranchID",General.BranchID},
                {"@FinancialYearID",General.FinancialYearID},
                {"@Type",Type},
                {"@FromDate",DateTime.ParseExact(FromDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)},
                {"@ToDate",DateTime.ParseExact(ToDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}                
            };  This is the paramarray object of SelectOutstandingReportDetailed

Comment: [DataTable.Load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.load?view=netframework-4.8) method is synchronous. So the main action - loading data - in your code happens synchronously.

Comment: What is the solution?@AlexanderPetrov

Comment: Truly asynchronous loading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45106131/5045688

Comment: Edited to make it simpler. Maybe is useful. Not tested code.

Comment: I found the problem and updated the question. Please check it.

Comment: In my solution the connection is open and closed always inside the `GetDataAsync` function. Just copy and paste my code, set the `connectionString ` variable with the value of your `ConnectionString ` variable and you're ready to go. Do you have a time to test my solution? I think it will fit your needs. Contact me if you get stuck with any errors