# DataGrid empty when loaded from async SqlDataReader

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, data-binding, datatable

I load a DataTable from a SqlDataReader, then databind it to a datagrid. When I execute the reader synchroniously, the datagrid gets loaded correctly. When I execute the reader asynchroniously, the datagrid is empty. Here is the code.

Synchronious - works

```
        async public Task<DataTable> GetDataTableAsync()
    {
        DataTable result = new DataTable();
        await this.Conn.OpenAsync();
        SqlDataReader reader = this.Comm.ExecuteReader();
        result.Load(reader);
        this.Conn.Close();
        return result;
    }
```

Asynchronious - doesn't work

```
        async public Task<DataTable> GetDataTableAsync()
    {
        DataTable result = new DataTable();
        await this.Conn.OpenAsync();
        SqlDataReader reader = await this.Comm.ExecuteReaderAsync();
        result.Load(reader);
        this.Conn.Close();
        return result;
    }
```

The DataTable comes out exactly the same in both cases.

The project is classic ASP.NET, the datagrid is Telerik RadGrid

Comment: What is a "this.Comm" ?

Comment: this.Comm is in instance of SqlCommand with the sql text and parameters

Answer (score 0):

So my answer is to explain ~why your code is not working.  And I added a SOF to help you find working code.

I think internally....

```
    result.Load(reader);
```

Does not call .ExecuteReaderAsync

So you are manually calling

```
SqlDataReader reader = await this.Comm.ExecuteReaderAsync();
```

(and doing nothing with it really)

And then .Load doesn't do anything with it either.

I think you're gonna have to chase

(see this answer)

[Populate C# DataTable Asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45105167/populate-c-sharp-datatable-asynchronously/45106131#45106131)

Comment: With a breakpoing, I see that the reader does get the records. But they don't get loaded into the DataTable after result.Load(reader);

Comment: You can look at the source code.  https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.data/system/Data/DataTable.cs      I doubt (as I mentioned previously).... .Load(reader) does not call/use ExecuteReaderAsync

Comment: Actually, I found out that the database gets filled up correctly in both cases. It is databinding that doesn' work, I edited the question for that.